# clases, objetos y funciones en python

Tags: python, poo

Soy noob en todo esto, estoy intentando aprender Python, estoy viendo POO pero tengo una duda. Qué se supone que hacen los paréntesis en estas líneas?

```py
    class ClasePrueba():
        pass
    print(type(ClasePrueba))
    print(type(ClasePrueba()))
    
    def funcionPrueba():
        pass
    
    print(type(funcionPrueba))
    print(type(funcionPrueba()))
```

La terminal me devuelve estas clases:

```
<class 'type'>
<class '__main__.ClasePrueba'>
<class 'function'>
<class 'NoneType'>
```

Yo entiendo que 'type' es una clase, ''**main**.ClasePrueba'' es un objeto de esa clase. 'Function' evidentemente es una función y NoneType pues es desconocido. Pero por qué lo cambia todo un ()?

Muchas gracias por vuestra sabiduría!

Answer (score 3):

## Los paréntesis cambian todo

EL hecho de que haya paréntesis después de poner el nombre de la función, clase o variable (no en la declaración de la función o clase, sino al hacer uso de ella) indica que el objeto es *"callable"* (que se puede llamar) lo que quiere decir que invoca al método `__call__` en las funciones, en las clases invoca al método `__new__` para crear un nuevo objeto.

El crear una clase significa crear un nuevo objeto, es decir un nuevo tipo de dato. La metaclase `type` devuelve el tipo de un objeto, si haz creado un objeto `Number` el tipo será `Number`, recordemos que en python todo es un objeto.

Para entrar más a fondo en el tema de los paréntesis recordemos que lo que siempre se guarda es una referencia a un objeto, si tenemos `texto = "un texto"` la variable `texto` tendrá una referencia al string guardado en memoria, esto mismo pasa con las clases y funciones, se guarda su definición y al utilizar los paréntesis se ejecuta todo ese código de la función o clase, veamos un ejemplo:

```py
#utilizamos una función nativa de python
print(print)
```

Al no tener paréntesis el `print` de adentro significa que solo nos devolverá la dirección de memoria de la función, si imprimes el tipo saldrá que es una built-in function.

## Tu código

En la primera parte de tu código estas creando un nuevo objeto

```py
class ClasePrueba():
    pass
print(type(ClasePrueba))
print(type(ClasePrueba()))
```

Al imprimir sin paréntesis solo se te regresará la dirección de memoria en la que se encuentra dicha clase, pero al utilizar los paréntesis se invoca al método `__new__` que crea al nuevo objeto y al utilizar `type` e devolverá el tipo, que será el nombre de la clase.

Con la función pasa casi lo mismo

```py
def funcionPrueba():
    pass

print(type(funcionPrueba))
print(type(funcionPrueba()))
```

Al no utilizar paréntesis te devuelve la dirección de memoria, pero al usar type te devuelve el tipo, que es `function`. Al usar los paréntesis se invoca `__call__` y se ejecuta la función, todas las funciones retornan `None` por defecto, al usar `type` lo haces en el resultado de la función, es decir haces `type(None)`, que obviamente regresará `NoneType`.

Comment: muchas gracias por la aclaración! vale oro :)

Answer (score -1):

me lo han aclarado por otro lado:

> ClasePrueba es una clase.
>
> ClasePrueba() es la invocación del constructor de esa clase lo cuál genera un objeto a partir de la clase.
>
> ClasePrueba, por lo tanto ese objeto es de ese tipo.
>
> funcionPrueba es una función.
>
> funcionPrueba() es la invocación de dicha función, por lo tanto lo que genera dependerá de qué devuelva la función. Como la función no tiene ningún return, entonces no hay nada y pues sería un None, creería sho, por eso dice NoneType.
>
> *Si a la función le pones un return 42, seguramente dirá que es un número.

Respuesta cortesía de [Edison Peñuela](https://www.facebook.com/edison.penuela) en Facebook.

Comment: Pues yo no he entendido nada :-)  Sin signos de puntuación lo que te han respondido me ha hecho saltar unas cuantas neuronas.  ¿Te importaria agregar la puntuación correctamente a la respuesta para que todos lo puedan entender?  Sino puede ser considerada de baja calidad y recibir votos negativos. Gracias.

Comment: Esto no es Facebook y se me descarrilaron varias neuronas tratando de procesar esa ensalada verbal.

Comment: Tenéis razón, culpa mía. No me di cuenta de que se juntaba todo el texto. Gracias por tomaros el tiempo para comentarlo! 